# Javascript - Left hand side assignment

Tags: javascript

I get a left hand side assignment error for the following code. I checked my equality operators over and over and I could not find something wrong.

```
function priceCal() {
    //declares
    var hourRate = 0.01;
    var dayRate = 7;
    var fullDayHours = 6 * 60;

    var dateStart = $('#datepickerStart').datepicker('getDate');
    var hourStart = $('#timepickerStart').timepicker('getTime');
    var dateEnd = $('#datepickerEnd').datepicker('getDate');
    var hourEnd = $('#timepickerEnd').timepicker('getTime');

    var totalDays = (dateEnd - dateStart) / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000; //we get total days
    var totalHours = (hourEnd - hourStart) / 60 / 1000;          //we get total minutes
    var startHours = (hourStart) / 60 / 1000;
    var endHours = (hourEnd) / 60 / 1000;

    var endRate = (hourEnd * hourRate);
    var startRate = (hourStart * hourRate);
    var daysRate = (totalDays * dayRate);

    // Both days are full
    if (totalDays > 0 && startHours >= 360 && endHours >= 360) {
        console.log("Rate is " + (totalDays * dayRate));
    }

    //Both days are not full
    if (totalDays > 0 && startHours < 360 && endHours < 360) {
        console.log("Rate is" + (totalDays * dayRate - 14) + (hourStart * hourRate) + (hourEnd * hourRate));
    }

    //Start day is full
    if (totalDays > 0 && startHours >= 360 && endHours < 360) {
        console.log("Rate is " = (totalDays * dayRate - 7) + (hourEnd * hourRate));
    }

    //End day is full
    if (totalDays > 0 && startHours < 360 && endHours >= 360) {
        console.log("Rate is " = (totalDays * dayRate - 7) + (hourStart * hourRate));
    }
```

Thank you in advance

EDIT: Really bad question, I was pretty reckless programming this script.

Comment: Is this on a browser? Most browsers not only tell you what the error is, but also WHERE it is. Did your browser not point you directly to the mistyped line?

Answer (score 2):

This is your error right here:

```
 console.log("Rate is " = (totalDays * dayRate - 7) + (hourEnd * hourRate));
```

Should be (if you want the equal sign that is):

```
 console.log("Rate is = " + (totalDays * dayRate - 7) + (hourEnd * hourRate));
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log("Rate is " = (totalDays * dayRate - 7) + (hourStart * hourRate));`

Missed the shift key looks like.

Comment: How do you get + when holding shift and =?

Comment: May be late but I'm pretty sure holding shift = you get +, which would make this a valid statement.

Comment: Before you get into an argument: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout

Comment: Well now I'm just curious. :)

Comment: Ha ha ha. Our retarded Swedish Keyboard layout :) SOrry about that.

Comment: Well TIL other keyboards besides QWERTY and Dvorak!

Comment: Well. Qwerty it is :)